# ExtJS check tree state

Tags: extjs, state

Is there a built-in/standard way to check a state of a tree (or component in general) - if it's loaded or not, rendered or not? There are listeners to react to these, but - the use case is if we can check if tree is loaded in delayed afterRender. It's easy to provide our own, but standard is preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that `tree.getView().getTreeStore().loading` exhibits the desired behavior. So unless I'm mistaken about its behavior or unless there are caveats/issues, that can be a solution

Comment: I'll wait before accepting this one in case someone reports there's a more appropriate solution (as I'm very new to ExtJS).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do the check if something is already rendered is to check for `.el.dom`:

```
if (Ext.getCmp("foobar").el && Ext.getCmp("foobar").el.dom) {
   // YES!!!
}
```

Btw, we use ExtJS 3, I'm not sure if this works with other versions of ExtJS too.